# Custom build step does not run at all

Tags: visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, I'd like to do some post build steps.

In Project Properties -> Custom Build Step -> General, I've added the following stuff,

[image]

And it's not working, I've tried to play with cmd.exe, but nothing pops up, what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, just figured out.

I need to fill the `Output` field, otherwise it won't run